# FaultException (.Net Framework)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, faultexception

I created a solution with Console App(.NET Framework) as the Server (net.tcp://0.0.0.0:8000/server) and WPF App(.NET Framework) as the client. There's an array with few names in that server and a method to search by index. From WPF client user can search names by index and it display the name. I created  a FaultException to throw if client requested index is out of the bound the array. And It is also handled in the WPF client. But the app crashes if the index is out of bound.

Server

```
public void Search(int index, out string name){
  if (index >= 0 && index < array.Length)
        {
            name = array[index];
        }
        else
        {
            throw new FaultException<SearchFault>(new SearchFault() { Message = "Not Found"});
        }
}
```

WPF Client

```
private void SBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = int.Parse(indexBox.Text) //This convertion exceptions are also handled. (I wont show here)
            string name = "";

            try
            {
                serverIntf.Search(index, out string name);

                nameBox.Text = name;

            }
            catch (FaultException<SearchFault> ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

[image]

[image]

Everything Tried, But Nothing worked.
Can anyone help me with this :(

Comment: What's your question? Nothing unexpected up to now...

Comment: What type of object is "array".  Put a break point in server and see the type.  It is probably a complex object.

Comment: @Fildor Then how it works...Im new to .net

Comment: Oh, wait. Is this WCF?

Comment: @Fildor yes it is

Comment: So,  there is an exception, even a FaultException, but your catch block is not matched? Try this: add another catch block after the existing one, catching `Exception`. That one should match nearly always. Then you should be able to investigate, why it does not match the first one.

Comment: @Fildor I tried.. But it didn't work. Same error

Comment: Where exactly is execution stopped? It may break a little prematurely, perhaps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255160/discussion-between-boots-and-fildor).

Comment: @Boots: `catch (Exception ex)` should always be executed. Did you put a breakpoint in the catch clause?

Comment: You can try using try-catch to handle any exceptions that may occur during this process.
Then use int.TryParse to safely convert the input from indexBox.Text to an integer. If the conversion fails, it will not throw an exception but will set the index to zero.